# Link to a custom controller in module openerp

Tags: python-2.7, controller, openerp-7

I created a custom controller with an action to download files that are automatically generated, the problem I am facing currently is how to link to this controller in the view without using a form tag (as the place of the link/button where I want it is already inside a form view), bellow is my controller:

```
class MyController(http.Controller):
  _cp_path = '/sc'

  @http.httprequest
  def some_html(self, req, s_action=None, **kw):
    return req.make_response(open('path_of_file').read(),
           [('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream; charset=binary'),
           ('Content-Disposition', content_disposition('1.docx', req))],
        )
```

Bellow is the xml view and where I want to place the link to the url to download the given docx (please note it is not a static file it's auto-generated):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_sefarer_applicant_form">
    ....
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Jobs - Recruitment Form" version="7.0">
      .....
        <sheet>
          <div class="oe_right oe_button_box">
            ...
            <button
                name="action_download_form"
                type="object"
                string="P014 Drug/Alcohol Delcaration"
                attrs="{'invisible':[('state','!=','done')]}"
                <!-- this is where the link to the download url
                     {sc/some_html} should be called -->
                />
            ...
        </sheet>
      </form>

    </field>
</record>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Dude did u get solution for the above question.I also want the same. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In order to get OpenERP to acknowledge your controller, you must have a `static` directory in your module directory:

```
/.../openerp/addons/MyModule/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __openerp__.py
    |-- controllers.py
    |-- static/
```